# Source of "Pattern t is deprecated. Use `_' instead" message

Tags: warning, libraries

Loading a certain file (that shall remain nameless) generates the message:

> Pattern t is deprecated.  Use `_' instead

No position information is given that would identify what expression generates the message. This looks to be from a library, rather than Emacs Lisp. What might be the source of this message (if possible to identify without source code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcase` (part of cl-lib) generates this message when usage conforms to:

```
(pcase ...
    ...
    (t ...)
)
```

To address the message, replace `t` with `_` (which is special to [`pcase`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/pcase-Macro.html#index-pcase-pattern)).

```
(pcase ...
    ...
    (_ ...)
)
```